# Stuck to understand angular array search

Tags: angularjs

see the code below.

i am new in angular. just do not understand this line

```
{{ (fields | filter : {fieldName:"houseNum"} : true)[0].fieldLabel}}
```

what is the meaning of **true in bracket** if we specify false like (`{{ (fields | filter : {fieldName:"houseNum"} : false)[0].fieldLabel}}`) then what will happen ?

### Full code

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{ (fields | filter : {fieldName:"houseNum"} : true)[0].fieldLabel}}
</div>


angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fields = [{
    fieldName: 'houseNum',
    fieldLabel: 'House Number',
    disabled: false
  }, {
    fieldName: 'street',
    fieldLabel: 'Street',
    disabled: false
  }, {
    fieldName: 'city',
    fieldLabel: 'City',
    disabled: true
  }, {
    fieldName: 'state',
    fieldLabel: 'State',
    disabled: true
  }, ]
})
```

sample taken from https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/q2r3cogj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

> Comparator which is used in determining if values retrieved using expression 
>       (when it is not a function) should be considered a match based on the the 
>       expected value (from the filter expression) and actual value (from the object 
>       in the array).
>
> Can be one of:
>
> function(actual, expected): The function will be given the object value and 
>       the predicate value to compare and should return true if both values should be 
>       considered equal.
>
> true: A shorthand for function(actual, expected) { return 
>       angular.equals(actual, expected)}. This is essentially strict comparison of 
>       expected and actual.
>
> false: A short hand for a function which will look for a substring match in a 
>       case insensitive way. Primitive values are converted to strings. Objects are 
>       not compared against primitives, unless they have a custom toString method 
>       (e.g. Date objects).
>
> Defaults to false.

So setting it to true requires an exact match for the item to be shown.  A false setting will allow for partial matches, case insensitive matches, etc.

Comment: can you please do me bit favor. i am new in angular. so i like to know how one controller function can call a function in another controller. can you please give me any relevant link which show me how to do it with code. thanks